# I'm importing excel using c # but I want to import the second page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, entity-framework

The library I use is microsoft.excel

I cannot use the first page of excel, I only work with the second page.How can I set the number of pages.

this is my code.

```
 excelFile.SaveAs(path);

 Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
 Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(path);
 Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
 Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;

 for (int i = 3; i <= range.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
      Google lm = new Google();

      lm.Default_channel_grouping = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[i, 1]).Text;
      lm.MonthOfYear = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[i, 2]).Text;
      lm.Date = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[i, 3]).Text;
      lm.Segment = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[i, 4]).Text;
      lm.Users = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[i, 5]).Text;
      lm.NewUsers = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[i, 6]).Text;
      lm.Ecommerce = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[i, 7]).Text;
      lm.Transactions = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[i, 7]).Text;
      lm.Revenue = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[i, 7]).Text;

      sdb.Google.Add(lm);
      sdb.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Comment: Excel doesn't have page, it has *sheets*. Your code doesn't import an Excel file, it starts Excel and reads cells one by one *as text*. This means that dates and numbers will be read as strings that will need parsiing. It would be better to use a library like eg [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) to load Excel files directly. You could import the data through SqlBulkCopy straight into the database instead of going through EF

Comment: BTW running Excel on the server is a very bad idea. 1) you need a license for every end user 2) unless you take great care, your code will keep starting Excel instances until the server runs out of memory

Comment: İşlemleri kendim yapacağım. Bu yüzden sorun çıkmayacak. Sadece işimi kolaylaştırmak istiyorum. Bir sorun olur mu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the number of sheets (I assume that's what you mean by pages) by accessing the [Sheets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets?view=excel-pia) property of the workbook:

```
 Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
 Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(path);
 var sheets = workbook.Sheets.Count;
```

To work with any sheet in the collection (in your case `i = 2`)

```
workbook.Sheets[i]
```

To add a sheet and make it active, use [Sheets.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets.add?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Sheets_Add_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_)

To select a worksheet as active:

```
((Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1]).Select();
```

Comment: Can you help me some more. I'm a little newbie. I added your codes but it still works on page first. 


                    for (int i = 3; i <= range.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Google lm = new Google();
                        ((Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[2]).Select();
                        lm.Default_channel_grouping = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[i, 1]).Text;
                        sdb.Google.Add(lm);
                        sdb.SaveChanges();
                    }